# Why is tab-completion (wildmenu) not working?

Tags: vim

My `.vimrc` contains:

```
set wildmenu                    " show list instead of just completing
set wildmode=list:longest,full  " command <Tab> completion, list matches, then longest common part, then all.
set wildignore+=.cache,.gem,.ivy2,.extras.bash,.themes
set wildignore+=.subversion,.subversion_IDEA
set wildignore+=.Trash
set wildignore+=Desktop,Documents,Downloads
set wildignore+=Library,Movies,Pictures
set wildignore+=spf13vim2
set wildignore+=.CFUserTextEncoding,.DS_Store
set wildignore+=.bash_history,.extra.bash,.irb-history
set wildignore+=.lesshst,.mysql_history,.pry_history
set wildignore+=.reviewboard-cache,.rnd,.sbt.cache.lock
set wildignore+=.scala_history,.sqlite_history,.viminfo
set wildignore+=*.o,*.obj,.git,vendor/rails/**,vendor/gems/**
set wildignore+=*.swp
```

You can find my full vimrc [here](https://github.com/roseperrone/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc). When I edit a file in vim, hitting `tab` produces spaces, but no autocompletion.

Comment: You're confusing _insert-mode completion_ with the _command-line_ wildmenu completion help.

Answer (score 6):

What?

The wildmenu is the menu that appears when you attempt tab-completion on the command line:

[image]

It's *totally* unrelated to insert mode completion and the settings in your question will *never* help you complete anything while editing a file.

Facts are better than speculation: you should get into the habit of reading Vim's internal documentation. The very first sentence of `:h 'wildmenu'` would have dissipated your confusion if you had taken the time to read it:

```
When 'wildmenu' is on, command-line completion operates in an enhanced mode.
```

Blindly copying settings from random internet sources will get you nowhere. Read the `:help`.

Comment: This could have done the job without the pedantic tone though.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if this was necessary, but tab-completion worked after I added this to my `.vimrc`:

```
function! Smart_TabComplete()
  let line = getline('.')                         " current line

  let substr = strpart(line, -1, col('.')+1)      " from the start of the current
                                                  " line to one character right
                                                  " of the cursor
  let substr = matchstr(substr, "[^ \t]*$")       " word till cursor
  if (strlen(substr)==0)                          " nothing to match on empty string
    return "\<tab>"
  endif
  let has_period = match(substr, '\.') != -1      " position of period, if any
  let has_slash = match(substr, '\/') != -1       " position of slash, if any
  if (!has_period && !has_slash)
    return "\<C-X>\<C-P>"                         " existing text matching
  elseif ( has_slash )
    return "\<C-X>\<C-F>"                         " file matching
  else
    return "\<C-X>\<C-O>"                         " plugin matching
  endif
endfunction

inoremap <tab> <c-r>=Smart_TabComplete()<CR>
```